# is there a way to just respawn php children processes without restarting php itself?

Tags: php, children

I'm running php-fpm and I'd like to shutdown and respawn php children without restarting php itself.

Comment: you want to do this from within php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is by using pcntl functions, [pcntl_fork()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) in particular would be your friend for this..

You can find many code examples on [this page](http://www.linuxformat.co.uk/wiki/index.php/PHP_-_Forking_processes).

**Trivial example:**

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();

if($pid) {
  // parent process runs what is here
  print "parent\n";
}
else {
  // child process runs what is here
  print "child\n";
}


// outputs:

child
parent
```

This is as simple as it gets, in real life you have a bit more to check for than this, do look at pcntl section on php.net, and a few of the code examples on the page I posted you. Hope that gets you on the right track, happy coding.